# cURL Multipart Post, how include file for Docebo API

Tags: php, api, curl, multipart

***Edit:***

I think I figured they want the key of the value containing the file.

So it should be:

```
$data = [
    "importMap" => "userid,firstname,lastname,email,new_password",
    "uploadedFileKey" => "@" . realpath("sample.csv"),
    "file_upload" => "uploadedFileKey",
    ...
];
```

Alas that returns a `(Error 500), Ouch! Something went wrong!` page. Probably that api method has been disabled.

*/end edit*

I'm working with the [Docebo API](https://www.docebo.com/lms-docebo-api-third-party-integration/) and every call I'm sending works fine besides when I want to include a file.

I'm pretty sure I'm not adding the file correctly to the postfield array, but I cannot figure out what my error is.

The API is asking for:

```
UserApiModuleStartSynchSchema {
    importMap (Array[string]): Array of columns identifying the columns of the CSV file. For all allowed column names, see notes above. ,
    file_url (string, optional): Publicly accessible URL where the CSV file can be downloaded from ,
    file_upload (string, optional): The name of the uploaded CSV file (via multipart POST) ,
    ...
}
```

I'm sending in the postfields:

```
$data = [
    "importMap" => "userid,firstname,lastname,email,new_password",
    "file_upload" => "sample.csv",
    "file" => "@" . realpath("sample.csv"),
    ...
];
```

I made sure the file exists, the content is correct and that the correct encoding is used.

File content is:

```
userid,firstname,lastname,email,new_password
marysmith,Mary,Smith,marysmith@example.com,fi5Zd90S
```

To be able to use the API you have to create a Authorization header that includes all postfields like this `implode(‘,’, $params)`. If I include my file there it will respond with a `Authorization header value doesn't match` if I include it after the header has been created it responds with `Error while reading uploaded CSV file`.

So I figured the second option would be the one to go, but I cannot figure out what made it fail reading the file.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? In PHP 5.6, uploading files with `@` is disabled by default, you have to use the `CURLFile` class.

Comment: I'm using 5.4.x, so CURLFile is not available.